# I want to make a function to find the closest value to n such that 32 % n = 0 in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make an efficient function that's described in the title of this question. Here is what I have tried, but I'm sure their is a better way. I'm using Java 8

Question: Is their a better way to implement this function that is more efficient?

```
private static double nearestMod(double n) {
        // Check if n already satisfies the condition
        if (32 % n == 0) {
            return n;
        }
        
        // Check if the solution can't be reasonably obtained
        if (n > 32) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        double increment;
        
        int numsAfterDecimalPoint = String.valueOf(n).split("\\.")[1].length();
        
        if (n % 1 == 0) {
            // If n is a whole number
            increment = 10;
        } else {
            increment = 1d / Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecimalPoint - 1);
        }

        double result = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        
        double multiplier = increment == 10 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecimalPoint);
        
        for (double i = n - increment * multiplier; i < n + increment * multiplier; i += increment / 10d) {
            double check = 32 / i;
            
            if (Math.abs(Math.round(check) - check) < increment / 10d && Math.abs(i - n) < Math.abs(result - n)) {
                result = i;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Example:
nearestMod(0.26) should return 0.25

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work? Does it throw an error? Are you just looking for general review and critique of working code?

Comment: Mainly looking for critique / more efficient way to do it because I couldn't think of one

Comment: Tree Dev, in that case this question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. You may want to direct this to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I think there is no good way except enumeration, because this is a thing for seeking prime numbers. If there is a good algorithm, there is no such encryption as aes.

Comment: sounds fair. I thought a gap in my abilities was what led to me using an iterative approach. I have found something pretty close though but not quite because this works in the opposite direction and does division. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-closest-n-divisible-m/